How to access f5-tts model without user interface
I am trying to build a project and I need to have an access to f5-tts model to use it dynamically.
I tried using it with user interface but that won't cut it. I want to give input to f5-tts in real time and get results back in real time. Is there any way I can do this? I wasn't able to find useful info elsewhere.
